# When does a Monad become a hammer?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, concepts, monad

I realize my precursory understanding on Monads is severely lacking in detail considering my knowledge comes mostly from [Douglas Crockford's Monads and Gonads talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc) and complicated with my sevear handicap with Haskell (which looks like a bunch of non-alpha numeric characters mushed between disjointed English words to my tragically disadvantaged brain).

With that being said, I'd like to ask about programming practices concerning Monads and how they could be implemented in JavaScript. I'm prefacing this because I recognize that the very nature of the language can drastically affect how one perceives a concept and that because of my background in JavaScript this question could be inappropriate if it were based in a purely functional language like Haskell.

Often times while designing an interface or coding an object I will find myself implementing a form of chaining which mutates the encapsulated data. I prefer this style over more declarative forms like passing in a multi-lined object literal.

```
function Declarative(options) {
  this.options = options;
}
Declarative.prototype.compute = function() { ... }
var x = new Declarative({
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
});
x.compute();
```

Verses:

```
function Chained() { }
Chained.prototype.withFoo = function(v) {
  this.foo = v;
  return this;
};
Chained.prototype.withBar = function(v) {
  this.bar = v;
  return this;
};
Chained.prototype.compute = function() { ... }
var x = new Chained()
  .withFoo('foo')
  .withBar('bar')
  .compute();
```

Both these examples (aesthetics aside) raise a few hairs on my back because a small voice mockingly squeals "Mutability much?" I begin thinking this might be a good time to conciser a Monad pattern. What I mean by that is each method would in short return a new object of the same type. Then adding composition functions on it like map, bind, etc. could off a world of potential like I get with Promises and other Monad type. (Obviously taking care to follow the three Monadic laws when implemented).

Finally, my other half of the brain starts chiming in with "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." Sigh. That is when my productivity and creativity crash here on SE curious and confused.

While I continue my research for understanding (perhaps gaining enough courage to contemplate Haskell) I ask: When does the idea of Monads (that being composability of functions on objects (ie types) along with immutability) become a good idea to be cultivated and patterned? And, when is it nothing more then an over utilized hammer?

(Concepts and learning opportunities welcomed, example code helpful)

Comment: When does it become "a hammer"?  When it's *all you have*.  "Pure functional" languages are crippled when it comes to mutable state (which, as scary as hard-line FP proponents try to make it sound, is *essential to any non-trivial program*,) so you end up seeing monads everywhere.

Comment: Pure rant. Doesn't fit here, try posting this as a blog item.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You see monads everywhere because being a monad is a property that lots of types happen to have (yes, including types that support mutable state); Haskell is (relatively) unique in allowing you to *talk* about that pattern. (In fact, most (or at least many) uses of monads in Haskell aren't about mutable state at all; I'm likelier to use `Maybe` (failure), `(->) a` (functions/global environment), or `[]` (lists/nondeterminism). Even if Haskell was impure (something that would, IMHO, "cripple" it even more), I think it would *still* be more expressive with monads than without.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler If mutability is *essential* to non-trivial programs, how do non-trivial programs get written in pure languages?

Comment: @MasonWheeler I wish I could downvote your comment. Multiple levels of fail in it: 1- Monads are not only about controlling mutable state. 2- FP doesn't forbid mutation, but is all about controlling it. 3- Non-trivial programs can and have been created using immutable data structures.

Comment: @Doval: By cheating, using tricks like State monads to pretend impure operations are being done purely.  For example: "Here we have a fake variable that we pretend represents 'the state of the entire outside world', and a fake pure function that takes the fake 'entire world' variable as an input and returns a modified world."  It's all incredibly silly what's going on if you look under the hood.

Comment: @AndresF.: I didn't say that's the only thing they're used for; I said *that's why they're used so commonly* and talked about so commonly.  Please don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @AndresF: You could also add that mutable variables are not the only way to model state, unless all you only know the imperative paradigm.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You've got it backwards - if anything, the monad lets you pretend pure functions are impure. There's no cheating and no tricks. There's no "fake pure functions" involved, nor "fake entire world". The functions *are* pure, and they *do* return a modified state. How else would they work? If you can't mutate existing values, returning modified copies is the only productive thing you can do. All the monad does is factor out the boilerplate of passing the output of the previous function to the next one in the chain. I guess DRY is silly?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You need not pass the entire world around as a variable. Think about state as a stream of snapshots. The real world does not really exist: what you can observe is just a sequence of snapshots taken at different points in time. Each element of the sequence (each snapshot) is immutable.

Comment: @Doval: If there's no cheating and no tricks involved, how do you read input as a pure function?

Comment: "The functional programmer sounds rather like a medieval monk, denying himself the pleasures of life in the hope that it will make him virtuous. To those more interested in material benefits, these “advantages” are not very convincing. Functional programmers argue that there are great material benefits ... [but] this is plainly ridiculous. **If omitting assignment statements brought such enormous benefits then [imperative] programmers would have been doing it for twenty years.** -- John Hughes, [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://tinyurl.com/25oze67) (Emphasis added.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler 1) Mutation is not IO. You're bringing up two completely different subjects and swapping them interchangeably. However, even the IO monad is pure, because a value of type `IO` doesn't actually *do* anything unless you return it from main. `putStr "Hello"` does nothing. `main = putStr "Hello"` does something. 2) That quote is a fallacy, because pure functional programming is still a relatively new field. You've also missed his point, which is that characterizing functional programming as taking away mutation misses the point - the point of FP is improved modularity.

Comment: @Doval: Still relatively new? Lisp has been around longer than anything except Fortran, and other functional languages appeared not long after.  And I'm not missing his point at all; his point is that dogmatic immutability (note: not *immutability in general*) is stupid, and the true benefits of functional programming lie elsewhere.  And he's right.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: "If there's no cheating and no tricks involved, how do you read input as a pure function?": Reading input is not a function. Period. On the other hand there are pure functions that create IO actions (which are no functions themselves). These IO actions can then be executed (using a mechanism that has nothing to do with function application) and read input.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You'd show you understood John Hughes if you quoted the part of his paper where he argues FP languages are "crippled" in regards to mutability, and that's why "you end up seeing monads everywhere". But I'm guessing you didn't understand the paper or his points :)

Comment: @AndresF.: Again, please stop putting words in my mouth.  I never said that John Hughes said that.  I never said anything remotely resembling that.

Comment: @MasonWheeler "If there's no cheating and no tricks involved, how do you read input as a pure function?" -- quite simply, you return an object from your pure function to an impure outer function.  The object contains a description of the input action you want to perform, and a function that will receive the result. The outer impure function performs the action, then calls the pure result function.  This is what the IO Monad is, at essence.  The nonsense about world states is a way of implementing that delays the impurity for as long as possible, but isn't necessary for it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, so this answer is aimed at providing more context about monads.  Some preliminaries about monads:

- Crockford's monad talk is a poor source for learning about monads (I hate to say this because he's so much smarter than me, and therefore probably understand monads better than I do, but IMHO it gives an inaccurate portrayal of monads).  So are [lots of other monad "tutorials"](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/abstraction-intuition-and-the-monad-tutorial-fallacy/).  If you don't put in hard work making your way through real examples, you'll probably never understand monads.
- monads are neither special nor magical.  They can be implemented in many (most? all?) programming languages without special support from the language/runtime/compiler/interpreter.  They aren't the end-all, be-all of functional programming.  But for some reason, they're what we hear about all the time.
- monads aren't unique.  There are many other [related datatypes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) which are useful in their own right.
- there are alternatives to monads, depending on what you want/need to do.  Search for "effects systems" and "algebraic effects".
- you can often get most/much of the value of monads without explicitly using them.  Just implement the combinators that you need and are useful and use them appropriately.  Recognize patterns in your code and factor them out, possibly capturing them as combinators.  If some of those combinators happen to match the requirements for `unit` and `join`, so be it.  That doesn't mean you have to think about what you're doing in terms of monads.  (But on the other hand, if you do use monads, you benefit from the numerous combinators already in existence for monads, as well as from writing super-generic code).

When is it inappropriate to use monads?

- if you have to warp your datatype or the monad laws in order to "make" a monad, you probably shouldn't do that, and should instead ask yourself why you're doing that
- if your code doesn't benefit from using a monad, or if it actually gets worse (whether because it's longer, or harder to understand, or harder to test, or harder to maintain, ... etc.), you're probably using monads inappropriately

Comment: `They aren't the end-all, be-all of functional programming. But for some reason, they're what we hear about all the time.` They're only practical with type inference and lambda expressions though. Using monads would be insane in Java 7. And I think that's why you hear about them so much - they're an example of what you simply can't do in languages where functions are second-class citizens. And as @AntalS-Z pointed out lots of types are monads, so it's an *entire class of things* you can't do rather than one obscure trick.

Comment: @Doval "They're only practical with type inference" -- nonsense.  "[...] entire class of things you can't do rather than one obscure trick" -- and again, you're elevating monads at the expense of [other useful datatypes and patterns](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia).

Comment: `nonsense` I expect a better rebuttal than this. The type signatures of high-order functions can get complicated quickly, even if their usage is intuitive. As an example, see the section "Typing" on [this Standard ML module](http://mlton.org/Fold). It gets even worse in C# and Java where functions are actually interfaces; curried functions become nested interfaces of the form `Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, T4>>>` and god help you if you have some `Optional`s, `Either`s or `Tuples` mixed in there. The type signatures can quickly become of equal or greater size than the lambda itself.

Comment: `and again, you're elevating monads at the expense of other useful datatypes and patterns.` No, I'm saying they're *more interesting* than some other useful datatypes and patterns. An imperative programmer won't be impressed with "things that can be mapped over" (i.e. a functor). Although he can't compose them with ease, he can already write functions to map from one type to another. Moreover, he'd rather write a loop than mess with `map`. Defining your own control structures, on the other hand, is something that's both compelling and completely out of an imperative language's reach.

Comment: @Doval in general, your posts seem to be pure regurgitation of your (or someone else's) biases without any attempt at critical thought.  You make statements such as "Defining your own control structures, on the other hand, is something that's both compelling and completely out of an imperative language's reach" and "They're only practical with type inference and lambda expressions though" without any attempt at supporting them or providing some justification that they are correct.  This essentially precludes any sort of constructive dialog.

Comment: Your comments are even more insubstantial; they amount to "no, you're wrong". Comment space is limited; I can't provide justification for *everything* I write. Have you *tried* implementing a monad in Java 7? In the worst case monadic code will use one lambda per line. The closest thing to a lambda in Java 7 is an anonymous class, which adds a minimum of 4 lines of boilerplate *per "lambda"*. For each anonymous class you'll have to write type annotations *twice* - once in the function interface's generics (e.g. `F<String, String>`) and again in the method signature. Do you call that practical?

Comment: Haskell has an incredibly concise syntax for lambda expressions and full-blown type inference and the designers of the language *still* added syntactic sugar to support monadic code.